# File Pointer Not Being Assigned a Value When Using fopen()

Tags: c, file, file-io

I am trying to write a simple C program which will read data from a csv file and perform some calculations on this data.

Unfortunately I have a problem where a file pointer of mine, `fptr` , is not being assigned a value after calling `fopen()`. I know this is the case after stepping through VS 2017's debugger. Yet I do not know why this is the case. This is a huge problem and means my program will throw some very nasty exceptions any time I try to read data from the file or close the file.

My code is below:

**main.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>         // For exit() function
#include"constants.h"       //For access to all project constants

/***************************************************************************************************************
To keep the terminal from automatically closing
Only useful for debugging/testing purposes
***************************************************************************************************************/
void preventTerminalClosure() {
    //flushes the standard input 
    //(clears the input buffer) 
    while ((getchar()) != '\n');
    printf("\n\nPress the ENTER key to close the terminal...\n");
    getchar();
}

/***************************************************************************************************************
Read the given input file
***************************************************************************************************************/
void readInputFile(char fileName[]) {
    FILE *fptr;
    char output[255];

    //open the file
    if (fptr = fopen(fileName, "r") != NULL) {          //read file if file exists
        //fscanf(fptr, "%[^\n]", output);
        //printf("Data from the file:\n%s", output);
        printf("<--Here-->");
    }else {                             
        printf("\nERROR 1: File %s not found\n", fileName);
        preventTerminalClosure();
        exit(1);
    }

    fclose(fptr);                       //close the file
}

/***************************************************************************************************************
                                        *   *   *   Main    *   *   *
***************************************************************************************************************/
void main() {
    char testName[MAX_NAME_SIZE];

    printf("Hello World!\n");
    printf("Please enter your name: ");
    scanf("%s", testName);

    printf("It's nice to meet you %s!", testName);

    readInputFile("dummy.txt");

    preventTerminalClosure();   //Debug only

}
```

I have made sure that my fake file does indeed exist and is located in the correct location. Otherwise my code would hit the `else` block inside of `readInputFile()`. That is something I have thoroughly tested.

There is clearly something basic that I am missing which explains this pointer behavior; but what that is, I am not sure. Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Maybe VS is trying to open the file in a different directory than you expect.  Is the file in the same directory as the executable?

Comment: You're missing some parentheses.

Comment: Is your compiler not warning you about this? I know gcc and clang will, not sure about msvc.

Comment: `if (fptr = fopen(fileName, "r") != NULL)` --> `if ((fptr = fopen(fileName, "r")) != NULL)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parenthesis to enforce order, so that `fptr` is compared against `NULL` after it has been assigned value returned by `fopen`:

```
FILE *fptr;
char output[255];

//open the file
if ( (fptr = fopen(fileName, "r")) != NULL)
```